# Create objects on the fly and access via parent class

Tags: oop, fortran

Currently i have class structure that is as follows:

```
 type, public :: ClassA      
    type(ClassB), public :: ObjectB
    type(ClassC), public :: ObjectC
 end type ClassA
```

So in words, if i create ObjectA somewhere else, i also create ObjectB and ObjectC. But i would rather want to have something like

```
type, public :: ClassA  
    contains
        procedure, public :: CreateObjectB
        procedure, public :: CreateObjectC
end type 
contains
subroutine CreateObjectB(self)
    class(ClassA) :: self
    type(ClassB) :: ObjectB
    ObjectB%initialized = 1
end subroutine
subroutine CreateObjectC(self)
    class(ClassA) :: self
    type(ClassC) :: ObjectC
    ObjectC%initialized = 1
end subroutine
```

So in words, just to have the possibility to create those objects.
And then, from the outside, i want to create the objects on the fly:

```
type(ClassA) :: ObjectA
call ObjectA%CreateObjectB()
print*,ObjectA%ObjectB%intialized
```

Assume ObjectB and ObjectC are properly defined (the variable "initialized" exists).
Currently i get the error "This is not a field name that is defined in the encompassing structure." from the print command.

I feel like i am close, but i can't get it to work. How do i do this?

Comment: it is *much* better if you provide you full example code, with ObjectB, ObjectC and etc defined and initalized, once the error may also be there.

Comment: Also notice that, by the way you define ObjectB inside CreateObjectB, ObjectB will only be available during that specific run of CreateObjectB. If you want it to be available after the subroutine is executed so you can call `print*,ObjectA%ObjectB%intialized` you must save it as a property of ClassA like you did in the beginning. Another option is to set CreateObjectB as a function and return it to the variable which the function is assigned.

Comment: Do you want to have a non determined amount of instances of and object inside an instance of another object?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow entirely so this may be off-target: if you want to be able to create an `A` without creating both a `B` and a `C` at the same time, you could make them both `allocatable` members of `type A`, then allocate them when you need to.  Or do you want to be able to create a `B` and later associate it with an `A` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by making the objects within the `classA` type `allocatable` like so:

```
module classA_module
        use classB_module
        use classC_module
implicit none
type :: classA
      type(classB), allocatable :: objectB
      type(classC), allocatable :: objectC
    contains
        procedure  :: init          => init_classA
        procedure  :: check_isInit  => check_isInit_classA
end type classA
        contains
                subroutine init_classA(this)
                        class(classA) :: this
                        allocate ( classB :: this%objectB )
                        allocate ( classC :: this%objectC )
                        ! initialize objectB (sets objectB%initialized = .true. internally)
                        call this%objectB%init()
                        call this%objectC%init()
                end subroutine init_classA
                subroutine check_isInit_classA(this)
                        class(classA) :: this
                        if ( this%objectB%isinitialized ) then
                                print*,'Initialization was successful'
                        else
                                print*,'Initialization failed'
                        endif
                        print*,'this%objectB%isinitialized: ',this%objectB%isinitialized
                        print*,'this%objectC%isinitialized: ',this%objectC%isinitialized
                end subroutine check_isInit_classA
end module classA_module

module classB_module
implicit none
type :: classB
        logical :: isInitialized = .false.
    contains
        procedure  :: init  => init_classB
end type classB
        contains
                subroutine init_classB(this)
                        class(classB) :: this
                        this%isInitialized = .true.
                end subroutine init_classB
end module classB_module

PROGRAM Main
      use classA_module
      implicit none
      type(classA) :: objectA
      call objectA%init()
      call objectA%check_isInit()
end program Main
```

I omitted the `classC_module` to save space. It is a copy/paste of `classB_module`, just replace B with C everywhere.